# jqGrid Form Editing отправлять PostData только измененные данные?

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Это продолжение темы [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35034794/jqgrid-modal-edit-save-only-changed-data-and-marked-edited-row)

В `Form Editing` при изменении любых данных и нажатии кнопки "Сохранить" на сервер отправляются все данные из этой формы.
Но я хочу сделать, чтобы отправлялись только те данные, которые были изменены в форме!
Один из вариантов:

1. Вешаем событие на

   ```
   .bind("jqGridAddEditBeforeShowForm", function (e, $form, oper) { 
       //  здесь получаем к примеру в переменную dirtyData начальные значения.
   }
   ```
2. При нажатии кнопки "Сохранить" мы проверяем `dirtyData` с текущими значениями данных на форме. Я думаю проверять нужно в

   `beforeSubmit : function(postdata, formid){ }`

Как лучше это сделать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Прежде всего, хотел бы обратить Ваше внимание на [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33544253/315935) на похожий вопрос, но касающийся inline editing модуса.

Вы можете решить проблему используя `onclickSubmit` с реализацией типа приведенной ниже

```js
onclickSubmit: function (options, postdata, editOrAdd) {
    var $self = $(this),
        p = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam"),
        rowid = postdata[p.id + "_id"],
        oldData, prop, oldValue, cm, formatoptions;

    if (editOrAdd === "edit") {
        // remove unchanged data from postdata
        oldData = $self.jqGrid("getRowData", rowid);
        for (prop in postdata) {
            if (postdata.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                oldValue = oldData[prop];

                if (p.iColByName[prop] != null) {
                    cm = p.colModel[p.iColByName[prop]];
                    formatoptions = cm.formatoptions || {};
                    if (cm.formatter === "date" && formatoptions.sendFormatted !== true) {
                        oldValue = $.unformat.date.call(this, oldValue, cm);
                    }
                }                               

                if (postdata[prop] === oldValue) {
                    delete postdata[prop]; 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

См [демо](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClickSendModified.htm). Обратите, кстати, внимание на изменение `beforeShowForm`, где я улучшил поддержку checkbox'ов.