# jqGrid afterclickPgButtons пропустить запись если isLeaf != TRUE?

Tags: php, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Я подгружаю начальные данные с сервера. Но данные treeGrid подгружаются с сервера только в момент открытия "дерева". В итоге при редактировании Edit Form я хочу сделать переходы по всем записям кроме 'Родителя'.
**Редактирую только данные Leaf**!
На самом деле данных много, есть и в которых не будет открыватся ничего. Но на скрине для наглядности я одного "родителя" сделал открытым.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    $("#bound").jqGrid({
    dataType : 'JSON',
    url: '/moderateStock/getBound.php',
    mtype: 'POST',
    editurl: '/editData.php',
    serializeEditData: function (postData) {
        postData.table = 'bound';
        return postData;
    },
    beforeRequest: function (){
          if(!!this.p.postData.nodeid) {
              this.p.url = '/moderateStock/getTreeBound.php';
          }
          else{
              this.p.url = '/moderateStock/getBound.php';
          }
    },
    loadComplete: function () {
    var $this = $(this);
        $("tr.jqgrow", $this).contextMenu('myMenuBound', {
          bindings: {
          'cm_boundEdit': function(trigger) {
          rowid = trigger.id;
          $this.typeEditView = 'cm_tm_table';
          $this.jqGrid("editGridRow", trigger.id, { 
                      recreateForm: true,
                      width: 1000,
                      height: "auto"});
          }
          },
    onContextMenu: function(event, menu) { 
                   var rowId = $(event.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id"), m = $this[0].p, data = m.data[m._index[rowId]], i, lastSelId;
                                i = $.inArray(rowId, m.selarrrow);
                                if (m.selrow !== rowId && i < 0) {
                                    $this.jqGrid('setSelection', rowId);
                                } 
                                return true;
    },
              formEditing: {
              closeOnEscape: true,
              closeAfterEdit: false,
              savekey: [false, 13],
              height: "auto",
              beforeShowForm: function ($form) { // on Edit
              if($(this)[0].typeEditView){
              var html_grid = '<div id="jqGridSubgridBoundWrapper" style="overflow: hidden"><table id="bound"></table><div id="bound_subgridPager"></div></div>';
                $(html_grid).insertBefore($('#FrmGrid_Bound', form));
               }
            }}})
  },
    colModel: [
                    { label: 'id', name: 'id', key: true,hidden: true},
                    { label: 'idTovar', name: 'idTovar',hidden: true},
                    { label: 'Группа',name: 'category'},
                    { label: 'Наименование', name: 'idPreparat',editable:true
                    },
              ],
    iconSet: "fontAwesome",
    treeGrid:true,
    ExpandColumn:'category',
    treedatatype:"json",
    treeGridModel:"adjacency",
    treeReader:{
         level_field: "level",
         parent_id_field: "parent", 
         leaf_field: "isLeaf",
         expanded_field: "expanded",
         loaded:true,
    },
    editable: true,
    gridview: true,
    caption: '',
    rownumbers: true
    }).jqGrid('filterToolbar',{searchOnEnter: false, searchOperators: true,stringResult:true,defaultSearch: 'cn'});
});
```

Данные с сервера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот эти данные мы получаем при открытии "Родителя" [JSON Tree](http://i.imgur.com/RnrzsGx.png)

Comment: Спасибо Олегу за помощь. Решение можно увидеть здесь -> [http://stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35693074/jqgrid-afterclickpgbuttons-skip-the-line-where-isleaf-non-is-true)

Comment: Пожалуйста, используйте один account. [Предыдущий вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/486912/198523) завис и он все еще не "принят".

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня складывается подозрение, что Вы используете TreeGrid не совсем в правильной ситуации, т.к. первые шесть колонок в leafs всегда пустые. К тому же использование двух разных url вызлядит странно. Возможно, что subgrid больше подошел бы. При этом основной грид был бы не редактируем, а subgrid - наоборот, редакнируемым. у основного грида была бы одно url, у subgrid'а - другая. Мне кажется, две бы стало проще и понятнее. В любом случае, следующие параметры можно спокойно удалить

```
treedatatype:"json",
treeReader:{
     level_field: "level",
     parent_id_field: "parent", 
     leaf_field: "isLeaf",
     expanded_field: "expanded",
     loaded:true,
},
editable: true,
gridview: true,
caption: '',
rownumbers: true
```

Я бы рекомендовал удалить и следующие столбцы

```
{ label: 'id', name: 'id', key: true,hidden: true},
{ label: 'idTovar', name: 'idTovar',hidden: true},
```

и использовать, вместо этого,

```
additionalProperties: ['id', 'idTovar']
```

При этом поля 'id' и 'idTovar' исходных данных ичитывались и сохронялись бы локально `getLocalRow` и параметр `data` содержали бы эти поля, но в DOM таблици ничего лишнего не было бы.

Что касается Вашего основного вопроса, то ответ но него я уже ранее написал [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35696682/315935).